# Checking if a certain class is in a list

Tags: python

I am trying to make it so lps_multipler gets mutiplied by 1.2 when burn is detected in list_of_status, and dividng lps_multipler by 1.2 when burn is not detected. but the following code runs the else statement aswell as the if statement at the same time.

```
    list_of_status = []
    list_of_status.append(StatusEffect(name="Burn", amount=999))
    list_of_status.append(StatusEffect(name="Testing Status", amount=1, timed=300))

    
for l in reversed( range(0, len(list_of_status)) ):
                BurnCheck = list_of_status[l]
                BurnCheck = BurnCheck.name
                if "Burn" in [BurnCheck]:
                    if lps_multiplier < 1.2:
                        lps_multiplier *= 1.2
                        updateTotalLPS(list_of_buildings)
                else:
                    lps_multiplier /= 1.2
                    updateTotalLPS(list_of_buildings)
                print(lps_multiplier)
```

Comment: `reversed(range(0, len(list_of_status)))` is excessive, especially when you only need the index to access the element it corresponds to. Use `for status in reversed(list_of_status)` directly.

Comment: Do you get this behavior in any case (whether 'Burn' is detected or not)? Note that because one `StatusEffect` object has 'Burn' and the other doesn't, you are obviously get both outputs from the loop. Do you get both outputs for each item in the list?

Comment: If burn isn't detected, it only divides. @IgnatiusReilly

Comment: [mre]..........

Comment: I can't reproduce it using a simple dummy `StatusEffect` that only has `self.name`, `self.amount`, etc and initial `lps_multiplier` set to either 1 or 10. Your code [works perfect](https://ideone.com/bgI1ao) for me. Please show a [mre] with a class definition and the initial value for `lps_multiplier`. Do not include `updateTotalLPS(list_of_buildings)` unless is necessary to reproduce the error.

Comment: The way your code is structured lps_multiplier will be divided by 1.2 for every item in list_of_status that does not have the name "Burn".   `if "Burn" in [BurnCheck]` is equivalent to `if list_of_status[l].name == "Burn"` so you're not checking for presence of absence of burn in the list,  what is happening is that you are repeating the process for every item.

Answer (score 1):

#### Debugging steps

Try adding these print statements and reporting back the results by pasting them in as text in the question (not an image).

```
for l in reversed( range(0, len(list_of_status)) ):
                BurnCheck = list_of_status[l]
                BurnCheck = BurnCheck.name
                
                print(f"l is {l}, lps_multiplier is {lps_multiplier}")

                if "Burn" in [BurnCheck]:
                    
                    print("  Burn found")

                    if lps_multiplier < 1.2:
                        lps_multiplier *= 1.2

                        print("    LPS being multplied")

                        updateTotalLPS(list_of_buildings)
                else:

                    print("  Burn not found")

                    lps_multiplier /= 1.2

                    print("    LPS being divided")

                    updateTotalLPS(list_of_buildings)
                print(lps_multiplier)
```